# How to send push notification to Flutter app from Asp.net core

Tags: api, flutter, push-notification, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a requirement where we need to send push notification to a flutter application ( android,iOS ) from .net core application. I spent sometimes searching on google but didn't find any suitable solution.

Comment: The easiest way is to use the firebaseCloudMessaging rest api https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: I think SignalR is a good solution for this, there’s even a [Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_client) package specifically for SignalR and asp.net core. SignalR works with websockets and given an open connection makes it possible to send out messages to clients from the server (both broadcasting to all clients as well as a specific client).

Comment: @JJuice and the message will appear as a notification on mobile device ?

Comment: @josh how can we send from .net core api ? We have already built api solution in .net core. Firebase cloud messaging is free or any cost is there ?

Comment: No showing them as notifications is step 2. But when you want to send out messages from .net core server code to your flutter app, I think SignalR is worth looking into. Then showing those messages as notifications is something you need to implement as well. There are several packages for flutter notifications.

Answer (score 0):

One way of sending push notifications to Flutter apps as previously mentioned in the comments is by using Firebase Cloud Messaging. With Firebase, it has an [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) that you can use on C# to generate registration tokens and be able to send push messages. You can check out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#c) for more details.

On your Flutter app, you'll need to use the [`firebase_messaging`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) package.